# help with formula to calculate Bayesian ranking of M-star reviews

Tags: bayesian, ranking, rating

I wonder, if someone could help to understand a formula from a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016060UHA) please.

Bayesian Methods for Hackers: Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Inference (Addison-Wesley Data & Analytics) (Addison-Wesley Data & Analytics) by Cameron Davidson-Pilon Davidson-Pilon

See also [this](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter4_TheGreatestTheoremNeverTold/Ch4_LawOfLargeNumbers_TFP.ipynb).

This is the formula:

[image]

I am not 100% sure what N and S is. Let us say there are 2 ratings. 1 for star 4 and 1 for star 5. Would N = 2 (2 ratings/votes/users) and S = 4 + 5 = 9?

Thanks!

PS:

I think this is related to [this](https://www.evanmiller.org/ranking-items-with-star-ratings.html), which I am sorry goes right over my head.

Comment: The quotation is explicit: it tells you $N$ is the number of possible **stars** in the rating system and "$S$ is the sum of all the ratings."

Comment: @whuber In the passage, N is used with two different meanings. It’s the latter that should be used, but yes, it’s explicit.

Comment: @Arya Excellent point: I overlooked the switch in meanings.  (One doesn't expect to see a variable that is introduced early in a paragraph to be completely redefined by the end!) I continue to lament the almost complete absence of real editorial review in publications during the last generation.

Comment: Guess this confuses me. So using my simple example, what do you think would be N and S?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is sloppy writing, and the author should be embarrassed :)

$N$ is the total number of ratings, and $S$ is the sum of "scores". Scores can be 1 or 0 (as in a binary voting system), or fractional (as in a star-rating system). I made a poor choice of variable names, and should have said:

> An M-star rating system can be seen as a more continuous version of the preceding, and we can set $m$ stars rewarded as equivalent a score of $\frac{m}{M}$

In your example: observing a rating 4 and a rating 5 (assuming that $M=5$ stars is the best possible score). Then $N=2$, and $S = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{5}{5}$.

Comment: +1.  I wish to reiterate that I attribute such lapses to editors, not to authors.  After you have written something it becomes extremely difficult to read it as it is on the paper instead of as you originally intended it.  That's why we need and value good editors!

Comment: Thanks so much @Cam.Davidson.Pilon - an answer from the author himself (-:

Comment: Sorry one more example 3 users. 2 vote 4 and 5. This means N=3 and S=(2*(4/5)) + (1*(5/5))? Thanks.

Comment: @cs0815 yup that's correct

Comment: @whuber, I absolutely agree. I've read this paragraph many times, and never once caught this haha